# want to replace with regex in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with content similar to the following. I want to remove all text between Bank Applicants (the numeric strings) using the find-and-replace functionality of Notepad++.

```
0004829 01-02 000421
0004830 01-02 000422
0466608 06-47 000743
Bank sl. no beginning with an 'IA' indicates ICB account
Paramount Textile Limited Page No: 143 of 258
Lottery Conducted by--Dept. of Electrical and Electronic Engineering, BUET. Date:03/10/2013
General
Applicants
0004823 01-02 000415
0004824 01-02 000416
0004826 01-02 000418
0004829 01-02 000421
0004830 01-02 000422
0004831 01-02 000423
0004832 01-02 000424
Bank sl. no beginning with a
Lottery Conducted by--Dept. of Electrical and Electronic Engineering, BUET. Date:03/10/2013
General
Applicants
0004823 01-02 000415
0004829 01-02 000421
0004830 01-02 000422
0004831 01-02 000423
0004832 01-02 000424
0004839 01-02 000431
0004840 01-02 000432
Bank sl. no beginning with an 'IA' indicates ICB account
and Electronic Engineering, BUET. Date:03/10/2013
General
Applicants
0004823 01-02 000415
0004830 01-02 000422
0004831 01-02 000423
0004832 01-02 000424
0004839 01-02 000431
```

An example of the output I want is as follows:

```
0004829 01-02 000421
0004830 01-02 000422
0466608 06-47 000743
0004823 01-02 000415
0004824 01-02 000416
0004826 01-02 000418
0004829 01-02 000421
0004830 01-02 000422
0004831 01-02 000423
0004832 01-02 000424
0004823 01-02 000415
0004829 01-02 000421
0004830 01-02 000422
0004831 01-02 000423
0004832 01-02 000424
0004839 01-02 000431
0004840 01-02 000432
0004823 01-02 000415
0004830 01-02 000422
0004831 01-02 000423
0004832 01-02 000424
0004839 01-02 000431
```

Answer (score 3):

Put notepad ++ search and replace in regex mode and search for `^[^0-9].*\r\n` replace with you should leave blank

make sure . does not match new line Picture below of settings and output [image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Find go to Mark tab. Find all lines that match "^000", enable option "Bookmark line", and click "Mark all". All lines similar to "0004829 01-02 000421" will be bookmarked.

Now remove all remaining lines: Search > Bookmark > Remove unmarked lines.

EDIT: Instead of "^000" better use "^[0-9]{3}".

Comment: @user1281385 I edit the answer. Your answer is simpler and should be the accepted answer. Mine answer uses different approach (bookmarks) that can in some other cases be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Regex to find anything other than your bank account numbers looks like:

```
^((?!\d{7}\s\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{6}).)*$
```

This searches for anything other than 7 digits followed by a space and then 2 digits followed by a hyphen and then other 2 digits and another space and 6 final digits.

You can use this to Mark all the lines that match this pattern and then remove the Marked Lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using vim, the regex would be :

```
g/^Bank/,/^Applicants/d
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

Find what: `Bank.+?Applicants\r?\n`
Replace with: `<nothing>`

then click on `Replace all`.

Make sure you have checked `Regular expression`  and `dot matches newline`